# Why can't I make a call to a function while in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, methods, jlabel

I am multithreading a background process on a JFrame window, and I want to update the text of a global JLabel variable inside a function.

So when the thread runs, my while and for loops run, but during them running, it makes the call to that other function to change the text.

However, it doesn't update until the thread finishes executing (i.e when the loops finish). Any reason why this happens, and how I can fix this?

If I try to just change the text of the JLabel inside the thread, it has the same result.

Comment: [Swing is not Thread-Safe!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)

Comment: Sounds like you’re trying to update ui from within the event dispatching thread, preventing ui from been updated - you’d be better off proving a runnable example which demonstrates your issue

Comment: Have you considered using a [progress bar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)?

Comment: I tried to reword your question to make it a bit better to read. But then, the comments are correct: A) multi threading and swing is complicated, are you using the correct approach B) probably a progress bar is what you should be looking at C) please read [mcve] and then edit/enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Use `SwingWorker` for updating GUI while a long running task/operation

Answer (score 2):

What might happened is your thread did make the change, but the screen display is not updated until the Swing event dispatch thread comes around and updates the display.  It is recommended and safer to call user interface updating methods using the Swing event dispatch thread.  You can do this by putting gui update code inside this method:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // call gui update here
    }
});
```

This still doesn't solve your problem yet (update happens after thread finish executing).  This is only to make it explicit that you are dealing with two threads here.  Your for loop on a separate thread will likely to  finish first because the drawing thread is usually slower.  However, knowing this will help you to plan which code to be passed to Swing event dispatch thread.  If you really want the for loop to update at that point in time, then you can put the entire for loop inside the `invokeLater()`.